# android webview full screen not call onShowCustomView

Tags: android, video, webview, fullscreen

according to the hint of this :

For full screen support, implementations of `WebChromeClient.onShowCustomView(android.view.View,android.webkit.WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback)` and `WebChromeClient.onHideCustomView()` are required.

i implementations this two function, and for most video,it work well, but in some cases, such as this link :

http://v.163.com/paike/V8H1BIE6U/VAG52A1KT.html

when i pressed the full screen control, `onShowCustomView` didn't called ,
i couldn't find out why, anyone who knows about this will be appricated.